# 1D Poisson equation with Neumann homogeneous boundary conditions. Finite Elements solution satisfies Neumann boundary conditions?

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, elliptic-equations

We have our PDE with Neumann boundary conditions, with $f \in L^2([0,1])$

$$ 
-\Delta u = f \quad \in [0,1], \quad \partial_x u(0) = \partial_x u(1) = 0
$$

With compatibility conditons $\int f dx = 0 $ and some uniqueness condition (say $\int u = 0 $ ).

The weak formulation of this problem is to find $u \in H^1$ satisfying
$$ \int_0^1 \dot u\ \dot v\ dx = \int_0^1 f v dx, \quad \forall v \in H^1$$

Typically, one solves numerically this problem employing the P1 finite elements: Take a spatial discretization $0 = x_0 < x_1 = 1/N < .... < x_n = 1 $, and then we replace the space $H^1$ by
$$ V_h = \{ v \in C([0,1])\ :\ v\big|_{[x_i, x_{i+1}]} \text{ is affine } \} $$

Then we take as ansatz $u$, our seeked solution, to belong in $V_h$, and we test with functions $v$ in $V_h$ too. This leads to the standard system

$$ 
\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \int_0^1 \dot \varphi_i(x) \dot \varphi_j(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \varphi_j(x) dx, \quad j =0,...,N
$$

where $\varphi_i$ are the hat functions that satisfies $\varphi_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

My question is: **Does the obtained discrete solution $u$ satisfies Neumann boundary conditions?**

To my understanding, Neumann boundary conditions in the space $V_h$ would correspond to $u_0 = u_1, u_{N-1} = u_N$.

Now, checking the system of equations at $j=0$ gives

$$ u_0 \int_0^1 \dot \varphi_0 (x) \dot \varphi_0(x) + u_1 \int_0^1 \dot \varphi_1 (x) \dot \varphi_0(x) = \int_0^1 f(x) \varphi_0(x) dx 
$$
replacing the values of the hat function gives

$$ u_0/N - u_1/N  = \int_0^{1/N} f(x) (1 - Nx) dx $$

Fair enough, if I have not made any mistake so far, it seems that the solution doesn't satisfies Neumann boundary condition. But, **does refining the mesh gives a solution with coefficients $|u_0 - u_1| \rightarrow 0$ ?**

I considered $ f(x) =1 $ for $x <1/2$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $x > 1/2$, then on the equation associated to $j=0$ we have

$$ \frac{u_0}{N} - \frac{u_1}{N} = \int_0^{1/N} (1-Nx) dx = \frac{1}{N} - N \frac{1}{2N^2} = \frac{1}{2N} $$

Which would imply $u_0 - u_1 = 1/2$ nomatter how refined is the problem.

My intuition tells me that this cannot be possible, being FEM the standard to numerically solve elliptic PDE's. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: First, in the correct terms, Neumann boundary conditions are called natural boundary conditions, Dirichlet - essential. Discrete solution will not satisfy natural conditions exactly, but it can be proved that in the limit it does, in the weak sense.

Comment: Perhaps part of your questions is answered at : [Stiffness matrix of a DGFEM for 1D steady state convection-diffusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281744/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my mistake, I misscalculated the equation associated to j=0, it is

$$ Nu_0 - Nu_1  = \int_0^{1/N} f(x) (1 - Nx) dx $$

From which we can see that indeed, the Neumann boundary conditions are not satisfied by the discrete solution, but when taking the limit of the the discretization width to zero ($\frac{1}{N} \rightarrow 0 $) then the values of $|u_0 - u_1| \rightarrow 0$.